# Slicing a reference of array

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, slice

I have the following map:

```
my %cps_per_level = (
                     Bronze      =>  [100 , 65  ],
                     Silver      =>  [200 , 125 ],
                     Gold        =>  [400 , 250 ],
                     Platinum    =>  [800 , 500 ],
                     Diamond     =>  [1200, 750 ],
                     Master      =>  [2000, 1200],
                     Grandmaster =>  [3000, 1750],
                );
```

In my code i want to get both values of the list for a particular entry to 2 variables. My first attempt was to de-reference the list for a particular entry then apply a list slice and assign that to the variables i want, like shown below. Here `$level` holds one key of the map.

```
my ($cps_before, $cps_after) = $cps_per_level{$level}[0,1];
```

But this doesn't work. `$cps_before` gets the first value of the list, but `$cps_after` gets nothing. I managed to make it work by writing this in 2 lines:

```
my $cps_before= $cps_per_level{$level}[0];
my $cps_after = $cps_per_level{$level}[1];
```

My question is: why didn't the slice work? What am i missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a slice. If you had an `@array`, a slice would look like this:

```
@array[0, 1, 2]
```

What you wrote is the equivalent of this:

```
$array[0, 1, 2]
```

... which uses `,` in scalar context and is equivalent to `$array[2]`.

In fact,

```
$cps_per_level{$level}[0,1]
```

is shorthand for

```
$cps_per_level{$level}->[0,1]
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
${ $cps_per_level{$level} }[0, 1]
```

which just means

```
${ $cps_per_level{$level} }[1]
```

What you should do instead is:

```
@{ $cps_per_level{$level} }[0, 1]
```

The `@` means you're trying to get multiple elements out.

If your perl is new enough (5.20 and no longer experimental since 5.24), you can also use a postfix dereference form like this:

```
$cps_per_level{$level}->@[0, 1]
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer. For what i see you de-reference the list with `@{...}` and then apply the slice to the de-referenced version of the list, which makes perfect sense. I guess my mistake was to think that the `->` (and it's syntactic sugar version `{...}[...]`) would de-reference anything automatically, instead of making it `${thing_to_derefence}[...]`.

Comment: @AndréSantos `@` and `[]` aren't separate constructs. `@ ... [ ]` is the syntax for an array slice. There's also a list slice operator, spelled `( ... )[ ]`. But you can't have a subscript of `[]` all by itself; it's always part of some bigger construct.